# Meteor's email package attachment

Tags: email, meteor, email-attachments

I'm poking around http://docs.meteor.com/#email .
It's pretty easy to send flat emails, but how can an attachment be added?
There's a comment in email.js:136 code:

```
// XXX support attachments (once we have a client/server-compatible binary 
// Buffer class)
```

Also Email uses MailComposer, which has method addAttachment(). Still it makes no sense about passing the attachment in Email.send() function.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The XXX means this feature is not implemented yet. I would recommend looking at some NPM packages for email. [`nodemailer`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/nodemailer) seems pretty popular.

Comment: thanks, nodemailer's does the thing

Comment: Check out my answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308994/sending-email-attachments-with-meteor-js-email-package-and-or-nodemailer-or-oth/30330188#30330188